# Run a program (not script) from Apache2 Ubuntu

Tags: python, apache

I have a working apache2 page, the sites-available calls a cgi script that starts with the line "#!/usr/bin/env python", and of course the rest of the script is a python program.

I have rewritten the program in C and have a working executable.

Is there a way I can run the executable from apache not the python script?

This in on a Ubuntu (12.04) server.

Thanks, Mark.

Edit...

As per user2853437 and furas suggested, I guess it is as simple as adding ".cgi" to the c binary filename.

I'm pretty sure I had tried that, but I did again and it seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: you should find the file, the script is called. Otherwise you may try to name your c executable exactly as the python file name. If it is not executed with another python script, it should work.

Comment: in folder `cgi` should work all executable programs/scripts - Python, Perl, C, Ruby, even PHP.